# in the middle of finishing rubymonk, what next?

Tags: ruby

I'm posting this somewhat in frustration after going through Rubymonk. I've finished Codeacademy and am mid-way through Rubymonk. I feel like I am getting bits and pieces about Ruby but do not feel like I'm getting anywhere near feeling comfortable in building a Ruby program from scratch.

My question is, are there places on the web where I can read source codes for small projects as they progress from easy to hard? or exercises to use some of my knowledge in a progressively more difficult manner? I certainly feel like I should begin by building smaller programs, but still want somewhat of a guidance. Should I just try to build whatever I want to build?

Thank you,

Comment: Most ruby books do just that: gradually build a program. So you should get one.

Comment: Best way is to come up with own small project idea and try to build from scratch :)

Comment: I suggest you sign up for the Core Ruby course at [Ruby Learning](http://rubylearning.org/classes/).  The course is long-running and well-designed, plus you get help from mentors.  There is a fee of $35 or $70, but it is well worth it. I see a new course starts tomorrow. Also, search on "Ruby" here at SO and read through Q's and A's of basic Ruby questions.  You'll learn a lot. Once you're comfortable with the basics, head over to [Rubeque](http://www.rubeque.com).  You'll find it difficult, but that's the idea.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of great resources for doing this. It sounds like you have some basic programming skills down, but it might not hurt to start with:

- the [online edition of Chris Pine's "Learn to Program."](https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/)
- [Learn Ruby The Hard Way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/) also gets good reviews, and is probably the closest to the spirit of what you're asking.
- [Code Quizzes](http://www.codequizzes.com/) has a Ruby track.
- [Ruby Quiz](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz120.html) has a great back log of more complicated puzzle questions.
- [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) is also a good puzzle problem resource, although it's not specifically for programming. The problems are very solvable with code, though, so it's a great source of inspiration.
- Some code schools also have their curriculum online. [Epicodus](http://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/) and [Portland Code School](https://github.com/portlandcodeschool/ruby-on-rails-2014Q1) are the ones I'm familiar with.

Hope that helps!